# What does the following mean?

Tags: word-requests, names

What does this mean in english if you translate it straight from japanese アントン . Im trying to write my name in japanese (Amy name is Anton) with japanese sign.

Answer (score 0):

アントン is not a Japanese word listed in Japanese dictionaries, so it's not translatable. アントン is merely a katakana rendering ([transliteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration)) of a foreign sound, and it does not have any special meaning as a Japanese word.